# jQuery Displaying array items give me [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/MKfLU/9/

i would like to know what are the values stored in my array so that it is easier for me to monitor what has been pushed in and splice out from the array. i have tried different method such as using `toString()`,

```
$.each(rowArray, function(index, value){
      newHTML.push('<span>'+value+'</span>');
});
      $("#test").html(newHTML.join(" , "));
```

and so on... and it always give me "[object, Object]". 
Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row in your array is a set of 2 objects. You should display their values like that:

```
for(i=0;i<existingRows.length;i++){
    $('#test').html(existingRows[i].type + ' ' + existingRows[i].number +'<br>');
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to info about all rows correctly, you should use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method, because using `html` replaces current HTML of the element - `append` adds content at the end of what there actually is.

```
$('#test').html(''); //clear current content
for(i=0;i<existingRows.length;i++){
    $('#test').append(existingRows[i].type + ' ' + existingRows[i].number +'<br>');
}
```

Comment: thank you :D +1 but it only displays the last one in the array? how can i display all elements in that array?

Comment: @yvonnezoe that's because you're replacing the content each time using `html` method. You should use `append` to add content to the end of current content. Check update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because `value` is an object.

Use `newHTML.push('<span>'+JSON.stringify(value)+'</span>');`